# Resource loader for an HTML5 and Javascript game

Tags: javascript, html5

I have made a type to shoot game using HTML5, Javascript and Ruby on Rails.
Here is the link for the game [Tweetraitor](http://tweetraitor.herokuapp.com)

I wanted to make a loader for resources (sounds, images) when the game starts. Currently when the game starts the background image takes time to load and it does not look good. This loader should load all the assets those are used later in the game.

Code for the game is here: [Tweetraitor on GitHub](https://github.com/rohit-jain/Tweetraitor)

In the current version, all the images are loaded using js in an [erb](https://github.com/rohit-jain/Tweetraitor/blob/master/app/views/guests/play.html.erb) file which controls the game logic. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Check this out: http://thinkpixellab.com/pxloader/ But it's pure JavaScript. This preloader is used in HTML5 version of Cut the Rope game

Answer (score 3):

I have to admit I have no idea of Ruby and how it's used together with js, but here is how I'd do it with js:

```
window.onload = function() {
        var sources = {
            resource1: "img/sprite1.png",
            resource2: "img/sprite2.png",
            resource3: "img/sprite3.png"
        };
        loadImages(sources, initGame);  // calls initGame after *all* images have finished loading
    };

    function loadImages(sources, callback) {
        var images = {};
        var loadedImages = 0;
        var numImages = 0;
        for (var src in sources) {
            numImages++;
        }
        for (var src in sources) {
            images[src] = new Image();
            images[src].onload = function(){
                if (++loadedImages >= numImages) {
                    callback(images);
                }
            };
            images[src].src = sources[src];
        }
    } 

    function initGame(images) {
        // some code here...
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. That's definitely better than what i am doing.

Comment: Note that when there is just one image which doesn't load for some reason, the game will load forever and there will be no error message. So you should also add an `.onerror` handler to the images you load.

Comment: Why not just use `numImages = sources.length;` instead of the for loop ?